# ProtoBuf - To String using serialisation

Tags: c#, asp.net, highcharts, protocol-buffers

I am using protobuf for serialisation to String. I have a report object to be passed to highchart template which I need to serialise to String. I am getting index out of bound exception while doing so. Please let me know why I am getting so. I am having one report object.

```
var report = new List<ReportViewModel>();
    report = CalculateOutputHelper.ConstructOverview(Convert.ToInt32(testId), eventName);           

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(stream, report);
            var tempOutPut = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());

            return tempOutPut;
        }
```

Comment: in witch line ?  `I am getting index out of bound exception while doing so`

Comment: Serializer.Serialize(stream, report);

Comment: Could you provide a little more of the surrounding code, so we can be a little more helpful? It's hard to help without enough context. I'm not as familiar with C# or Protocol Buffers, but it will help others more familiar with those to help you better.

Comment: To fix your error look your data....

Comment: report is an object which is used as input to highchart template.

Comment: report object is as attached below. Other JSON serialisers using JIL and service stack works fine. I am trying various methods to see the performance.

Comment: -     TimeAxis null double[]
  Title "Engine Speed" string
  XAxis null double[]
  xMax 2219790.0 double
  xMin 0.0 double
  XTitle "Time (microseconds)" string
  YTitle "Engine Speed (rpm)" string
+  Raw View

Comment: I am passing report object which is a List<ReportViewModel>. Is it ok to pass list object as an input to Serializer.Serialize() in protobuf-net.